# Lookup between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, lookup

I have a dataframe like below from an API response:

[image]

However, The API can give more variables like street, direction etc., So, I need to create an output from the API response which automatically define null. Example like below

[image]

For this I created a list of all the variables I want in the output and tried and match API response dataframe to the output dataframe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use: `df[['street', 'direction']] = None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by list, if column not exist is filled by missing values:

```
L = ['house','house_number',..., 'street', 'direction']
df = df1.reindex(L, axis=1)
```

Comment: In the question it says he creates a **list** of variables not a dataframe with column names